# Text editors with built-in terminal?

Tags: terminal, text-editor

I've found [Kate](http://kate-editor.org) when I tried out SUSE; I've become 'addicted' to the built-in terminal feature that no other editor seems to have. The terminal can be automatically synchronized to the built-in file explorer, which I've found very useful.

What other editor exists for environments other than KDE with support for a built-in terminal? Like for GNOME? Windows? I'm looking for something intuitive and easy to use (like Kate, Notepad++), and **not** Emacs or Vim.

Comment: How is this not programming related? Do you normally write your programs with "echo" and "cat"?

Answer (score 5):

Emacs, of course.  Can't say if it works on every platform, but Windows, linux and most unixes support it.

Answer (score 1):

Gedit supports this via a plugin in the standard plugins package.  http://live.gnome.org/GeditPlugins

Answer (score 0):

Coda has terminal built in I believe.

Answer (score 0):

[anjuta](http://www.anjuta.org) also has it

Answer (score 0):

[UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultraedit.html) for Windows has built-in [SSH/Telnet terminal](http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/ssh_telnet.html).

Answer (score 0):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) has a Console plugin.

You'll also want to add the Project Viewer plugin to get the side panels and also the LookAndFeel plugin so that you can make it less ugly!